# В чем отличие инструментов в отладчике step и step into?

Tags: javascript, отладка, google-chrome-devtools, отладчик

Вроде бы они работают одинаково ну или очень похоже: просто "ходят" по выполняемому коду.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не может же быть в "Инструментах разработчика" два одинаковых инструмента, выполняющих одно и то же. В чем отличие?

Answer (score 3):

Всё ддовольно просто. **Step Into** предназначен для входа ВНУТРЬ процедуры.

А просто **Step** - просто выполнит её, молча, и только покажет Вам результат.

Это актуально, когда Вы стоите на каком то вызове типа `x = GetOptimalValue(y);`, и думаете "А хочу я посмотреть, как вычисляется это оптимальное значение, или мне достаточно просто увидеть результат вычисления?"

Соответственно, при нажатии **Step Into** вы вопадаете внутрь процедуры GetOptimalValue(), а при нажатии просто **Step** - у вас происходит переход к следующей строке кода, но при этом "под капотом" процедура `GetOptimalValue()` уже выполнилась и вернула результат.

Конечно, есть и строки, в котрых оба инструмента работают одинаково: на `x = y;` их действие будет абсолютно одинаковым.

(Ну, если только x и y это не сложные объекты, у которых переопределен конструктор присваивания)

Comment: Решила сделать пример, похожий на тот, который вы привели, и отличий не вижу (может не туда смотрю). [Вот код](https://jsfiddle.net/bLj356p0/).

Comment: Если я беру `step`, я сначала нахожусь на вызове функции, потом перехожу во внутрь этой функции, функция возвращает `50`, потом выхожу из этой функции, потом перехожу к строке с объявлением переменной и присвоением ей возвращаемого значения функции. Сначала объявляется переменная - `func: undefined`, потом выполняется функция, идет "заход" внутрь самой функции - функция опять возвращает значение - `Return value: 50`. Дальше обратно переход к переменной - `func` присваивается 50.

Comment: _Step Into предназначен для входа ВНУТРЬ процедуры._  `step` вроде как тоже внутрь входит. Присваивая значение переменой, он позволяет входить в саму функцию и там делает `return`. Точно также работает и `step out` в этом случае - один в один

Comment: Зня гугл, я предположу, что где то есть галочка "использовать Step как Step Into". Но я ответ писал "по мотивам" других отладчиков, сейчас попробую поэкспериментировать с этим...

Comment: то есть такое поведение `step` можно изменить в настройках?